# Why has xclip -loop 1 stopped working?

Tags: linux, clipboard, xclip

If I use e.g.

```
  echo 'test' | xclip -i -selection primary -loops 1 -quiet
```

and paste into another terminal window, it works as expected, i.e. 'test' is pasted and then the primary selection goes back to the previous client, 'test' is gone. However, if I paste into an X program, this does not work. If I use `-loops 10`, I can see that 'test' is pasted to the application on the fourth loop in e.g. gedit and a webkit browser, in firefox it is even the seventh loop. If I use `xsel` instead, I get the following behaviour:

```
echo 'test' | xsel -i -p -n -vvvv
xsel: Window id: 0x2e00001 (unmapped)
xsel: Timestamp: 2495171514
xsel: Maximum request size: 4000 bytes
xsel: Accumulated 5 bytes input
xsel: handle_selection_request, property=0x1ca (<unknown atom>), target=0x23d (<unknown atom>)
xsel: Refusing conversion
xsel: handle_selection_request, property=0x1ca (<unknown atom>), target=0x1a9 (TARGETS)
xsel: change_property ()
xsel: data within maximum request size
xsel: Confirming conversion
xsel: handle_selection_request, property=0x1ca (<unknown atom>), target=0x121 (UTF8_STRING)
xsel: change_property ()
xsel: data within maximum request size
xsel: Confirming conversion
```

The same happens if I use `clipboard` instead of `primary`. What happens in the first few loops and where does the data go?

Note: This is of interest since in password managers, you may want to paste the password *exactly* once...

Another note: I remember that this used to work at some point in the past, probably on an old Ubuntu version. Now I can reproduce this behaviour on Ubuntu 12.04 and also on Debian testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [following Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=738643):

> I use `xclip -l 1` to paste stuff to Iceweasel. This used to work very 
>   well, but broke in Iceweasel 26. This is because Iceweasel 26 probes the 
>   PRIMARY clipboard for TARGETS multiple times before it actually requests 
>   the UTF8_STRING contents, which causes xclip to exit prematurely. 
>   Upstream committed a fix for this behavior:
>   http://sourceforge.net/p/xclip/code/85/
>   I would be grateful if you cherry-picked the patch for Debian. Thanks
>   for considering.

To solve apply [the following patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/xclip/code/85) and recompile:

```
-- a/trunk/xclib.c
+++ b/trunk/xclib.c
@@ -411,6 +411,10 @@
    XSendEvent(dpy, evt.xselectionrequest.requestor, 0, 0, &res);
    XFlush(dpy);

+   /* don't treat TARGETS request as contents request */
+   if (evt.xselectionrequest.target == targets)
+       return 0;
+
    /* if len < chunk_size, then the data was sent all at
     * once and the transfer is now complete, return 1
     */
```

http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=collab-maint/xclip.git;a=blob_plain;f=debian/patches/01_dont-treat-TARGETS-as-contents.patch;h=1fe637d7ca9ee6ac1dbf8ea4b68ae0381e7558e2;hb=ba750dfa3a9527aede5ac1d8ebc9b98979433b87